# I can't provide internet using DHCP server

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet, dhcp-server

I have the follwing Network, the DHCP + Internet are provided by the router "TP-Link N600" and I want to add DHCP rule on our server instead of the router, so how can I provide internet to the AP's and laptops.

Is it using gateway?

[image: Network Scheme]

Comment: The AP's are layer 2 devices and don't need internet access. The AP clients need internet access. You have to create a Scope in DHCP on your server and configure it with the correct settings for the clients, including DNS servers and router.

Comment: Well - what have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it has a desired end state, it does not show any thought of what he has tried and/or any issues he encountered trying to configure his environment.

Comment: Do you just want to change what device is providing DHCP? Or are you trying to change what device provides the gateway to the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading this correct, you would like to disable the DHCP service in your TP-Link N600, and setup your 2K8 box to start providing addresses via its DHCP Role. Is this correct?

If so, then from Server Manager, add the DHCP role. Create your scope, define some exclusions (if needed) and let it rock on. Make sure to add your DNS servers and Router options in the DHCP setups. I believe they are options 003 and 006. Once you get it setup, disable the DHCP server on the router and issue a ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew, and ipconfig /flushdns on one of the clients and see if it pulls an address in.

Comment: Thank you so much @Factory909. As you said, I want to disable the dhcp server from router and setup a dhcp server rule on windows server. the problem is "the router was providing me internet so should i set the gateway on server 192.168.1.1 or what?

Comment: Yes, set the gateway on the server as that of the router. And then in DHCP management, make sure the router option is set so your DHCP clients will also know the gateway.